# path, angle = line.strip().split() ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

Code:

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import islice

LIMIT = None

DATA_FOLDER = 'driving_dataset'
TRAIN_FILE = os.path.join(DATA_FOLDER, 'data.txt')

def preprocess(img):
    resized = cv2.resize((cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV))[:, :, 1], (100, 100))
    return resized

def return_data():

    X = []
    y = []
    features = []

    with open(TRAIN_FILE) as fp:
        for line in islice(fp, LIMIT):
            path, angle = line.strip().split()
            full_path = os.path.join(DATA_FOLDER, path)
            X.append(full_path)
            # using angles from -pi to pi to avoid rescaling the atan in the network
            y.append(float(angle) * scipy.pi / 180)

    for i in range(len(X)):
        img = plt.imread(X[i])
        features.append(preprocess(img))

    features = np.array(features).astype('float32')
    labels = np.array(y).astype('float32')

    with open("features", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(features, f, protocol=4)
    with open("labels", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(labels, f, protocol=4)

return_data()
```

Error:

```
  path, angle = line.strip().split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Ready I got an Autopilot code when I use the code to extract the data
I'm Getting An Error Like This I Don't Know What To Do Exactly
My Python Version Latest Version
Thanks in advance

Comment: seems like you are getting more than two values at line `path, angle = line.strip().split()`, you can see that by `print(line)` just before the line which is throwing error. or you can share the output of `print(line)`

Comment: Do you have a chance to make the edited version of the code and share it?

Comment: Please read [ask] and ask a question, ending with `?`, with proper capitalization. Also, show the steps you tried following to solve the problem yourself, and explain what happened when you tried those steps.

Comment: sorry, the edit queue is full. you can plug this code and then decide which value you need for path and angle. `for line in islice(fp, LIMIT):
    print(f"Read Line: {line}") #==> new line of code
    path, angle = line.strip().split()`

Comment: I'm sorry I'll be more careful.

Comment: I Solved My Problem Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That means there is a line in your data.txt file with more than two space separated values. You are trying to put more than two values into two variables, which causes an error.

If you only want the first two values try this:

`path, angle, *_ = line.strip().split()`

This will assign the remaining values into `_`.

If this is not what you want then either your data.txt file is the problem, or you need to add more variables, for example:

`path, angle, and, more, variables = line.strip().split()`

EDIT

If i understand correctly, a single line looks like this

`0.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:44:912`

and you are trying to get `'0.jpg'` as `path`, and `0.00000` as `angle`. To achieve this you first have to get rid of everything after the comma, then split the remaining string by spaces. For example

```py
line = line.strip().split(',')[0] # get rid of everything after the comma
path, angle = line.strip().split() # split the rest on spaces
```

Comment: ```path, angle, *_ = line.strip().split()' ```   Doesn't read them in date.txt file when I Replace With This  ```y.append(float(angle) * scipy.pi / 180)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.000000,2018-07-01' ```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Could you post some example lines from your data.txt?

Comment: ```0.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:44:912
1.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:44:972
2.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:45:11
3.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:45:76
4.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:45:105
5.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:45:145
6.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:45:205
7.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:45:246
8.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:45:301
9.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:45:341
10.jpg 0.000000,2018-07-01 17:09:45:407``` some of the ingredients.